# Ruby's optimized implementation of Histogram/Aggregator

Tags: ruby, histogram, aggregator

i'm about to write my own but i was wondering if there are any gems/libs that i can use as aggregator/histogram

my goal would be to sum up values based on a matching key:

```
["fish","2"]
["fish","40"]
["meat","56"]
["meat","1"]
```

Should sum op the values per unique key and return `["fish","42"]` and `["meat","57"]`
.The files i have to aggregate are relatively large, about 4gb text files made of tsv key/value pair
.My goal is to try not to use temporary files in order not to take too much space on the machine, so i was wondering if something similar already optimized already exists, i have found a jeb on github named 'histogram' but it does not really contain the functionalities i need
Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Hash with a default value of 0 to do the counting, then in the end you could convert it to Array to yield the format you want, though I think you might just want to keep using the Hash instead.

```
data = [
  ["fish","2"],
  ["fish","40"],
  ["meat","56"],
  ["meat","1"]
]

hist = data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(k,v), h|
  h[k] += v.to_i
end

hist # => {"fish"=>42, "meat"=>57}
hist.to_a # => [["fish", 42], ["meat", 57]]
# To get String values, "42" instead of 42, etc:
hist.map { |k,v| [k, v.to_s] } # => [["fish", "42"], ["meat", "57"]]
```

Since you stated you had to read the data from a file, here is the above when applied to a file. The `input.txt` file contents are as follows for this example:

```
fish,2
fish,40
meat,56
meat,1
```

Then, to create the same output as before by reading it line by line:

```
file = File.open('input.txt')

hist = file.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |line, h|      
  key, value = line.split(',')
  h[key] += value.to_i
end

file.close
```

Comment: change just `42` to `'42'`, `57` to `'57'` etc

Comment: I noticed he mentioned Strings as return values, but since they are numbers I figured he might actually want Fixnums instead so I left it like that ;)

Comment: If so.. I would reduce me code.. that's the reason.. my one got so longgg :-)

Comment: Hehe. Yours is a bit longer anyway with group_by, 2x map, inject ;). But thanks, I edited for String values.